# Shuffling grouped list with ordering such that element of same group does not appear one after another in java

Tags: java, arraylist, random, java-8

I have a list of Media objects.

```
Class structure of Media is :
Integer id;
String url;
(@ManyToOne)EventEntity event,..etc

Class structure of EventEntity is :

Integer id;
String name;....etc
```

There can be multiple `Media` objects of same `EventEntity`. How can we randomly sort `Media` list such that `Media` object of same `EventEntity` does not appear one after another.

For example, My desired result is:

```
[
{
"abc",event1
},
{
"sdf",event2
},
{
"sdf34",event1
},
{
"sdsdafsdf",event3
},
{
"sdf345f34",event2
}
]
```

Also I can create another class->`Demo.class`:

```
Integer id;
String url;
Integer eventId;
```

And populate the `List<Demo>` and randomize.
The output should be :

```
[
    {
    5,"abc",1
    },
    {
    8,"sdf",2
    },
    {
    1,"sdf34",1
    },
    {
    2,"sdsdafsdf",3
    },
    {
    9,"sdf345f34",2
    }
    ]
```

Please suggest with some description.Java 8 is preferable, as well as older version whichever is more efficient.

Update :
`List<Media>` can have unequal number of elements for different `EventEntity`.
For example : `List<Media>` has 8 elements of which 5 have the same `EventEntity`.

In this case, the random order will be done but may not follow the rule but should come close to it.

Comment: And what should happen if a `List<Media>` has 5 elements of which 4 have the same `EventEntity` ?

Comment: @RobinTopper Good question, if that's the case then, simple randomize will be done. The list may or may not contain same number of object for different events.

Comment: Randomness and structural constraints are on the opposite sides of the scale. You have to decide how much priority these contradicting goals have.

Comment: @Holger First priority is the rule which is for ideal case/

Comment: You should replace your Javascript/JSON/whatever notation with actual Java code and type signatures. How are we supposed to know the meaning of the numbers in, e.g. `{  2,"sdsdafsdf",3  }`?

Comment: @Holger I have yet to write code. Thatswhy I am trying to get suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is

```
List<Media> result = new ArrayList<>(mediaCollection.size());

ArrayList<Media> flatList = new ArrayList<>(mediaCollection);
Map<Integer,Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();
for(Media m: flatList)
    countMap.merge(m.getEventEntity().getId(), 1, Integer::sum);

Random r = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
Collections.shuffle(flatList, r);

Integer previousID = null;
while(!flatList.isEmpty()) {
    for(int index = flatList.size()-1; index >= 0; index--) {
        final Media m = flatList.get(index);
        Integer id = m.getEventEntity().getId();
        if(previousID!=null && previousID.equals(id) && countMap.size()>1) continue;
        previousID = id;
        result.add(m);
        flatList.remove(index);
        countMap.merge(id, -1, (a,b) -> a==1? null: a+b);
    }
    if(countMap.size() == 1) {
        result.addAll(flatList);
        flatList.clear();
    }
}
```

This copies all elements into `flatList` to shuffle them, then, while copying them to the final `result` list, elements having the same ID as their previous are postponed to the next copying iteration (usually, only a few elements are left after the first step). The critical part is to stop when only elements with the same ID are left, as then, postponing has no point and would lead to an infinite loop. That’s why the `countMap` is maintained. It keeps track of how many of each ID are left whereas entries are removed when they would go to zero. When the map has a size of one, only one ID is left and the remaining elements are transferred en bloc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you tell me about the efficiency ?

Comment: Well, `Collections.shuffle` is as efficient as possible for the task. The costs of the rest of the code are ignorable. The average time complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: I will try your suggestion, I have also implemented `Collections.shuffle`.